# polynomial in recurrence relation using matrrix exponential

Tags: recurrence-relations, matrix-exponential

I have my recurrence relation as `f(n) = a*f(n-1) + b*f(n-2) + n*n` how to solve that relation using matrix exponential

I have tried like

```
| f(n)   |   | a b 1 | ^ (n-1)       |  f(1) |
| f(n-1) | = | 1 0 0 |           *   |  f(0) |
| f(n-2) |   | 1 0 0 |               |  n*n  |
```

but it fails due to base matrix contains n*n in the last row how could I solve this using matrix exponential.

Comment: I see no reason for matrix exponential to intervene here unless your instructor has said that there is a solution with this tool...

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking that when you have a recurrence $f_n = af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}$, then it defines a matrix recurrence $\def\f{{\bf f}}\f_n=A\f_{n-1}$ whose solution is $\f_n=A^{n-1}\f_1$. Here, 
$$\f_n=\begin{bmatrix}f_n\\f_{n-1}\end{bmatrix},\qquad A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Unfortunately, things do not work out so cleanly in your problem. Let 
$
\def\b{{\bf b}}\b = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},
$ the recurrence is now
$$
\f_n = A\f_{n-1} +n^2\b 
$$
Instead, the solution is now
$$
\f_n = A^{n-1}\f_1 + A^{n-2}\b 2^2 + A^{n-3}\b 3^2 + \dots + A\b({n-1})^2 +\b n^2
$$
Noting that $A$ is invertible, we can write this as 
$$
\f_n = A^{n-1}\f_1 + A^{n}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n k^2A^{-k}\right)\b
$$
There does exist a closed form for $\sum_{k=2}^n k^2A^{-k}$, but it is messy. In general, the closed form for
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n k^2x^k
$$
can be bound by starting with the equation $x^2 + x^3 + \dots + x^n=\frac{x^2-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, the differentiating both sides, then multiplying by $x$, then differentiating again, then multiplying by $x$ again. You can then substitute $x=A^{-1}$ into the resulting formula.

However, I think this method will only work when $A$ does not have $1$ as an eigenvalue. More subtle methods would be required in the case.

---

There is a different way to approach the problem. Take the four equations
$$
\begin{align}
f_n &= af_{n-1} + bf_{n-2} + n^2\tag{a}\\
f_{n-1} &= af_{n-2} + bf_{n-3} + (n-1)^2\tag{b}\\
f_{n-2} &= af_{n-3} + bf_{n-4} + (n-2)^2\tag{c}\\
f_{n-3} &= af_{n-4} + bf_{n-5} + (n-3)^2\tag{d}\\
\end{align}
$$
and consider the equation $(a)-3(b)+3(c)-(d)$. You will find that this new equation is a recurrence for $f_n$ in terms of $f_{n-1},f_{n-2},\dots,f_{n-5}$, where there is no longer an $n^2$. You can then solve this new recurrence with a matrix exponential.